# swift coredata - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When setting an attribute (NSSet) of an NSManagedObject for coredata, it will display this error at runtime:

```
-[__NSArray0 isEqualToSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1551ad60
```

First, I have no idea which instance is identified as 0x1551ad60.

Second, I understand the instance doesn't understand 'isEqualToSet', however I am not calling it anywhere in my code which must mean it is called by the framework somewhere? I'm guessing my code is incorrect but I don't understand how or where.

I am running Xcode 7.3 with Swift (2.0 I think?) and I have removed/reinstalled the app many times on the iPad.

Here is my code, the problem line is marked. Please help, this is driving me mad!

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let carEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Car", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let carObj = NSManagedObject(entity: carEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    carObj.setValue("Toyota", forKey: "name")
    carObj.setValue("Blue", forKey: "colour")

    let wheelEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Wheel", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    let wheelObj = NSManagedObject(entity: wheelEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    wheelObj.setValue(Float(1.3), forKey: "tread")

(Original code)
var wheelObjArray = [NSManagedObject]()
wheelObjArray.append(wheelObj)
let wheelSet = NSSet(array: wheelObjArray)
carObj.setValue(wheelSet, forKey: "wheels")
^^ error here: unrecognized selector sent to instance
(/Original code)

(Edited code)
var wheelObjArray = carObj.mutableSetValueForKey("wheels")
wheelObjArray.addObject(wheelObj)
^^ error here: *** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet
(/Edited code)

do {
    try managedContext.save()
    print("Success!")
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Failed to save: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

My CoreData model is as follows:

[image: Car]

[image: Wheel]

Edit: Car relationship "wheels" is now a one-to-many relationship.

Edit #2: Code updated.

Edit #3: One possible workaround for this problem is to remove the inverse relationship from Wheel "car".

Comment: It seems that your relationship is set to one-to-one on both sides, which you may want to change `wheels` to `to many`

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, I would have encountered that problem later.

Answer (score 0):

```
var wheel_obj_array = [NSManagedObject]()
```

should be

```
var wheel_obj_array = car_obj.mutableSetValueForKey("wheels")
wheel_obj_array.addObject(wheel_obj)
```

Also shouldn't really use _ in vars its very difficult to read anything.

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions, I have updated it however it has created the following error: *** -[NSSet intersectsSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet - on this line: wheelObjArray.addObject(wheelObj)

Comment: is the relationship one to one in both directions?

Comment: I have updated Car "wheels" to become one-to-many and uninstalled/reinstalled the app however the new error is still showing.

Comment: Have you deleted the  let wheel_set : NSSet = NSSet(array: wheel_obj_array)
    car_obj.setValue(wheel_set, forKey: "wheels")

Comment: I have now and the same error remains. The problem code appeared before the now deleted lines.

Comment: Can you add the now current code in another code block above as an edit please :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108836/discussion-between-user328414-and-seanlintern88).

Answer (score 0):

`car_obj.setValue(NSSet(object: wheel_obj), forKey: "wheels")` should work.

And `wheel_obj.setValue(car_obj, forKey: "relationship")` will automatically set the reverse relationship, which *might* be easier to write and read.

BTW, you may want to change the relationship in `Wheel` to `car` instead the current *confusing* `relationship`.

Comment: car_obj.setValue(NSSet(object: wheel_obj), forKey("wheels")) didn't work so I tried car_obj.setValue(NSSet(object: wheel_obj), forKey: "wheels") and there was no change to the error :(

Comment: It's better / easier to use the second option I mentioned. The error seems to be "to many" is not properly set. You could verify this by automatically generating 'NSManagedObject' subclasses in Menu > Editor while selecting your .xcdatamodeId file

Answer (score -1):

in my case it works by removing NSSet. When the error is happened the code that I used was :

```
project.setValue(NSSet(object: agent), forKey: "agent")
```

Then to make it works I changed it to :

```
project.setValue(object: agent, forKey: "agent")
```

thank you